# Broadcast message in IRC Client (chatbot) C#

Tags: c#, irc

Здравствуйте, пишу **IRC клиент**, для общения с внутренним сервером [IRC](https://help.twitch.tv/customer/en/portal/articles/1302780-twitch-irc) [твича](https://www.twitch.tv) и столкнулся с такой проблемой:
 не работает запрос к серверу с многострочным сообщением(список команд), т.к **StreamWriter** при использовании метода Flush(), отправляет данные Tcp клиенту не пачкой, а кусками **ИЛИ** сам tcpClient отсылает запрос кусками, не суть. Вообщем запрос делится на куски:(. В результате в случае построчной записи списка команд в поток, сообщение вообще не выводится.

**Пробовал**
отправлять запрос с сообщением одной строкой с "\n" в нужных местах - обрезает все что после первой строки команды (выводит первую строку списка команд в чат)

**Вопрос**: можно ли отправить irc серверу запрос с *многострочным* сообщением или нет? Если да, то как? Код прикрепляю:

```
    public void sendChatMessage(string message)
    {
        sendIrcMessage(":" + userName + "!" + userName + "@" + userName + "twi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #" + channel + " :@" + senderName + " " + message);
    }

    public void sendChatBroadcastChatMessage(string message)
    {
        sendIrcMessage(":" + userName + "!" + userName + "@" + userName + "twi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #" + channel + " : " + message);
    }

    public void sendChatBroadcastChatMessage(List<string> messages)
    {
        messages.Insert(0, ":" + userName + "!" + userName + "@" + userName + "twi.twitch.tv PRIVMSG #" + channel + " : ");
        sendIrcMessage(messages);
    }
```

userName - имя бота, channel - название канала

```
    private void sendIrcMessage(List<string> messages)
    {
        try
        {
            if (outputStream == null)
                throw new Exception("Output stream is empty...");
            foreach (var item in messages)
            {
                outputStream.WriteLine(item);
            }
            outputStream.Flush();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
            return;
        }
    }
```

messages в данном случае - список команд:

```
        "!hi - приветствие",
        "!date - дата и время сервера",
        "!commands - список команд"
```

Итак, вызывается sendChatBroadcastChatMessage(messages). В нем в начало сообщения добавляется запрос и вызывается метод sendIrcMessage(messages) с обновленным списком. Надеюсь рассказал достаточно подробно...

**Ответ сервера:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На en-so говорят, что протокол IRC запрещает многострочные ссобщения, ссылаясь на RFC 1459.

См. тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13898584/insert-line-breaks-into-an-irc-message

Открываем RFC: https://rfc2.ru/1459.rfc/print

> IRC-сообщения всегда выглядят как строки символов, заканчивающихся
>   парой символов CR-LF (Carriage Return - Line Feed. Возврат Каретки -
>   Перевод Строки) и длиной строки, не превышающей 512 символов (в эти
>   512 входят и CR-LF). Так что, максимальная длина строки для команд и
>   параметров - 510 символов. Перенос строки невозможен. Для более
>   подробной информации смотрите раздел 7.

Так что, увы, видимо нет:

> можно ли отправить irc серверу запрос с *многострочным* сообщением или
>   нет? Если да, то как?

Надо ещё посмореть, не было с тех пор новых стандартов, переопределяющих этот RFC.

Вот список стандартов для начала просмотра:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хм...печально, спасибо что указали, с чем работать)